# Combine two active_callbacks into one on theme customizer

Tags: functions, theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm using the theme customizer where I'm trying to find a way to check two settings. Here's my code and an explanation what it does:

```
// start a setting called 'twsa_show_active_days'
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'twsa_show_active_days' );
// add options to the setting, in this case a radio to select three options
$wp_customize->add_control( 'twsa_show_active_days', array(
'description' => 'Weekdays and/or weekends?',
'type' => 'radio',
'section' => 'twsa_show',
'choices' => array(
    'weekdays' => 'Weekdays',
    'plus_sat' => 'Weekdays plus Saturday',
    'full_week' => 'Weekdays plus Saturday & Sunday'),
// active callback to check if 'active' is selected in another setting
'active_callback' => function() use ( $wp_customize ) {
    return 'active' === $wp_customize->get_setting( 'twsa_show_schedule' )->value();
},
// another active_callback to check if 'twsa_show_active' is selected in another setting
'active_callback' => function() use ( $wp_customize ) {
    return 'daily' === $wp_customize->get_setting( 'twsa_show_active' )->value();
}) );
```

My question is, how do you use `active_callback` to check two settings? It works on one setting but I need it to check two settings. Do I need to create a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misreading your question, but combining these two conditions in one anonymous function doesn't look that difficult:

```
'active_callback' => function() use ( $wp_customize ) {
    $condition1 == $wp_customize->get_setting( 'twsa_show_schedule' )->value();
    $condition2 == $wp_customize->get_setting( 'twsa_show_active' )->value();
    return ($condition1 && $condition2); 
    }
```

For really smart thinking on active callbacks, [read Otto's take on them](http://ottopress.com/2015/whats-new-with-the-customizer/).

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks! I was able to solve my problem by creating a function that checks two settings: `(( $control->manager->get_setting('twsa_show_schedule')->value() == 'active' ) && ($control->manager->get_setting('twsa_show_active')->value() == 'monthly' ))`

Answer (score 0):

In general, there should not be any limitation on what is being checked in `active_callback` or how the code is written. There should not be any limitation about checking two (or more) settings at the same time.